# Linqpad - Outputting into anchor to use title

Tags: linqpad

I have a db that stores exception messages.
I would like to create a query that gets these exceptions but instead of dumping huge amounts of text i would prefer it to be "on demand".

I figured putting the exception into an anchor tag like so and then reading the message when needed by mousing over it would work... apparently not.

```
var logsForErrors = (from error in Logs
         select new {
              error = LINQPad.Util.RawHtml("<a title='"+ error.Exception+"'></a>"),
              errorDate = error.Date,
              errorMessage = error.Message
         }).Take(10);

logsForErrors.Dump();
```

This is throwing an exception (lol) - "Cannot parse custom HTML: "

Encoding the exception message

```
...RawHtml("<a title='"+ Uri.EscapeDataString(error.Exception)+"'></a>")
```

> Message   Could not translate expression 'RawHtml((("h__TransparentIdentifier0.error.Exception)) +
>   "'>"))' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression. 
>   will generate a new error

Any ideas? - I am open to alternative solutions to this also.

I just want a container for the message instead of it just dumping right into the output as it it so huge!.

Thanks,
Kohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the "Results to DataGrids" mode in the recent betas? It might do just what you need without having to write anything else.

Edit: your error was probably due to emitting HTML without escaping the text. The easiest solution is to call Util.RawHtml with an XElement instead of a string. You could write an extension method that does what you want like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object Tooltipize (this string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (data) || data.Length < 20) return data;
        return Util.RawHtml (new XElement ("span", new XAttribute ("title", data), data.Substring (0, 20)));
    }
}
```

Put this into **My Extensions** and you can use it from any query.

Comment: I completely forgot about that. The tabular nature certainly works along the lines that i needed and i can mouse over the cells for a tooltip. It's not exactly how i wanted it, and i like write a lot of extensions to format data in the rich text output. But i'll happily use this for now. Many thanks.